# Make a soap request via php SoapClient

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I have to make a SOAP request but I'm facing some problems because using SoapClient I can't get the same XML that is supposed.

This is the correct xml request

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <wsse:Security
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>10983</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>test2019</wsse:Password>
            <Context>10000Hoteis</Context>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <OTA_ReadRQ xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05/common"
            xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" TimeStamp="2015-07-16T06:38:10.60">
            <ReadRequests>
                <HotelReadRequest>
                    <TPA_Extensions>
                        <RequestType>GetCities</RequestType>
                        <CountryCode>PT</CountryCode>
                    </TPA_Extensions>
                </HotelReadRequest>
            </ReadRequests>
        </OTA_ReadRQ>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

And this is my current php code

```
 $xmlheader = <<<XML
        <wsse:Security
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>myusername</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>mypassword</wsse:Password>
            <Context>10000Hoteis</Context>
        </wsse:Security>
XML;
$xmlbody = <<<XML

        <OTA_ReadRQ xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05/common"
                xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" TimeStamp="2015-07-16T06:38:10.60">
                <ReadRequests>
                        <HotelReadRequest>
                                <TPA_Extensions>
                                        <RequestType>GetCities</RequestType>
                                        <CountryCode>PT</CountryCode>
                                </TPA_Extensions>
                        </HotelReadRequest>
                </ReadRequests>
        </OTA_ReadRQ>

XML;
$headerXML = new \SoapVar($xmlheader,XSD_ANYXML);
$body = new \SoapVar($xmlbody,XSD_ANYXML);
$client = new \SoapClient(null, ['location' => 'http://10000hoteis.com.pt/NewAvailabilityServlet/staticdata/OTA2014A', 'uri' =>'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' ,'trace' => true]);

$header = new \SoapHeader('http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd', 'Security', $headerXML);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);  
$result = $client->OTA_ReadRQ($body);
```

But this don't work because put an extra

```
<SOAP-ENV:OTA_ReadRQ>
```

between the body tag and

```
<OTA_ReadRQ xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05/common"
                xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" TimeStamp="2015-07-16T06:38:10.60">
```

How can I do this request correctly?

Comment: You shouldn't need to build XML manually, you should be able to just pass arrays of parameters to `$client->OTA_ReadRQ` to build the request.

Comment: @miken32 and how can I add for example this
`xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05/common"
                xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" TimeStamp="2015-07-16T06:38:10.60"`
To the OTA_ReadRQ tag?